# was7 throwing servletException not logged in SystemOut.log file

Tags: eclipse, websphere-7, servletexception

I am working with code deployed on Websphere Application Server 7 that throws a ServletException as follows:

```
if (BaseConvertors.isEmpty(email)) {
    throw new ServletException("Invalid url access - not authenticated.");
}
```

`email` is a `String`.

When I debug the servlet in Eclipse, I see the stack trace printed out in the console. But there is no indication of the exception in the `SystemOut.log` file. This code is inside the `doGet` method which throws the exception itself.

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {}
```

How do I get the exception to be logged in `SystemOut.log` file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error gets logged into SystemError.log ... duh !

Comment: You should mark your answer as Accepted if it solved your problem.